# Connect wp-users database with application login and register

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost

If i want a registration  account in application and stored the information of an user in user site for Wordpress, can I store the information of user in wp-users database for Wordpress in localhost also?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can store the user information on wp-users table. Make sure for specifying the designation of the users.. Before giving designation for users, please read the below link http://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/user-role/